# Contour plot in r over a map

Tags: r, ggplot2, netcdf

Have to do a contour plot over a map in r programming the data is in netcdf format and extracted the required variables and subsetted the area with k=lat long boundaries now using plotly, ggplot2, lattice library, maps library but both contour plot and map is not combining.

```r
library(RNetCDF)
library(maps)
library(ggplot2)
file<- open.nc("D:\\folder\\data\\AERDB_D3_VIIRS_NOAA20.A2022335.002.2023083220857.nc")
aOt<-var.get.nc(file,"Aerosol_Optical_Thickness_550_Land_Ocean_Mean")
lat<-var.get.nc(file, "Latitude")
lon<-var.get.nc(file,"Longitude")
lat_min<-0
lat_max<-35
lon_min<-66
lon_max<-100
subset_data<-aOt[lat >= lat_min & lat<= lat_max & lon>= lon_min & lon<= lon_max]
class(subset_data)
subset_data_df<-na.omit(as.data.frame(subset_data))
```

I have subsetted the data as seen here and want to creat an contour plot over a mapof the given lat long location.